# How to setup DSN for Oracle database in Windows 7?

Tags: sql, r, odbc, windows-7-x64, rodbc

Let me preface this by stating that I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing with regard to setting up or connecting to an Oracle database. I know SQL syntax, but I've never had to worry about connections myself.

My end goal is to connect to a specific database using the RODBC package in R. If you can instead provide me an alternative package to use in order to connect to my database in R, I'd be happy with that too. I am currently connecting to this database through Oracle SQL Developer, but would like to access the data directly through R. Generic connection details to this database that I have setup in SQL Developer are listed below:

```
Connection Name: connection1
Username: user1
Password: password1
Connection Type: Basic
Hostname: ABCDEF
Port: 51500
SID: sid1
```

After my initial failure with RODBC, I read that I need to create a DSN in Windows. I've tried to create the DSN using MySQL, Oracle in XE, and SQL Server drivers, using every combination of the connection details listed above that makes sense. I've failed every time. Am I going about this wrong? Is there a simple set of instructions I can follow to set up the DSN, or is there a way around that while still being able to access the database in R? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: odbc connections on win7 are seriously non-intuitive. There are two odbc administrators for win7 - 32 bit and 64 bit. You have to make sure you are using the right one. This superuser post has more: http://superuser.com/questions/419832/how-can-i-open-the-32-bit-odbc-data-source-administrator-in-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: I think that may have helped me solve part of the problem -- I see a whole lot of new drivers available to choose from now. Any idea which I should be choosing though? The one I would have thought, Microsoft ODBC for Oracle, gives me an error message stating the component isn't installed.

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Install Instant Client (Basic + ODBC)**

32-bit
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

64-bit
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

All files unzip in C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1\

cmd.exe run C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1\odbc_install.exe

**2. TNS**

Create C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

Add TNS configuration in tnsnames.ora

Add system Environment Variable TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

Restart computer

**3. ODBC**

32-bit
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

64-bit
C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe

Add system data source

Driver is "Oracle in instantclient_12_1"

**4. Connection**

DSN=(data source name);Uid=(user);Pwd=(password);

Please try this.